# iOS - Show View when phone is locked

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm building an ios app with an alarm feature. I would like to show a view when phone is locked. I want to look exactly like on iOS alarm. If you're an iPhone user try to alarm and locked your phone you will get what i'm talking about. Is it possible? If possible how?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS doesn't provide apps that kind of access to the lock screen (or any screen not in your app), so it's impossible to make it exactly like the iOS native alarm. The closest you can get is sending notifications to simulate an alarm, which are visible on the lock screen

Comment: you mean like local notification

Comment: Okay thanks. I'll mark this as correct answer later it says "You can accept answer in 6 minutes"